Cant run two way data binding in angular
Im trying to use two way data binding in angular. I also did before in the same project and its working. But despite of im using same way in different component, last one is not working.
My component name is "navbar" and here is my code
<input type="search" class="form-control" placeholder="Type to search"  [(ngModel)]="navbarSearchKey"/>

import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormControl, FormGroup, FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { ItemQuery } from '../../models/itemQuery';
import { SearchService } from '../../services/search.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-navbar',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [RouterModule,FormsModule],
  templateUrl: './navbar.component.html',
  styleUrl: './navbar.component.scss',
})
export class NavbarComponent implements OnInit{

  itemList!: ItemQuery[];
  navbarSearchKey:string='';


are there any errors in console?

No my friend, its just not binding

what is the log on ngModelChange for this.navbarSearchKey ? and just a friendly reminder that you don't need to give type string when you're already assigning string to it. TS will automatically typecast it to string since you're defining string on initialization.

where can i see that?

<input type="search" class="form-control" placeholder="Type to search"  [(ngModel)]="navbarSearchKey" (ngModelChange)="logFunction()"/> and console.log(this.navbarSearcKey) inside logFunction

there is nothing more in the console. last changes didnt write anything in the console

It's strange... I created a sample and it works https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-gur63k?file=src%2Fmain.ts

Its already working when you change on the back. But i want to change it with user input like you know. I cant see if its changing with user input. Am i miss something idk. I used stackblitz for the first time just know. And i liked it btw xd
